# Pandas Calculation Errors

Tags: python, pandas, fibonacci

I am trying to calculate the Fibonacci retractment Level in Python.

I am calculating the Fibonacci levels with the following function:

```
def fibonacci(x, v=0.786):
    closemax = x.max()
    closemin = x.min()
    return closemax - ((closemax - closemin) * v)


data_2["fibonacci786up"] = (
    data_2.groupby(["DateTime"])["Close"]
    .expanding(1)
    .apply(lambda x: fibonacci(x, 0.786))
).values
```

This gets me the following Dataframe:

```
              Close  Day  fibonacci786up  fibonacci618up  fibonacci382up  \
DateTime                                                                   
2022-09-22  0.98346   22        1.007020        1.007020        1.007020   
2022-09-22  0.98321   22        1.007405        1.007708        1.008132   
2022-09-22  0.98383   22        1.007405        1.007708        1.008132   
2022-09-23  0.98433   23        1.007405        1.007708        1.008132   
2022-09-23  0.98371   23        1.007405        1.007708        1.008132   
2022-09-23  0.98278   23        1.007467        1.007818        1.008312   
2022-09-23  0.98233   23        1.008597        1.009835        1.011575   
2022-09-23  0.98227   23        1.009254        1.011008        1.013472   
2022-09-23  0.98293   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.98121   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97751   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97530   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97622   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97500   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97511   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97555   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97339   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97045   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97171   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.97070   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.96907   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.96725   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.96910   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523   
2022-09-23  0.96885   23        1.009618        1.011657        1.014523
```

The Issue with this is that the calculations are completely wrong.

For example the Fibonacci calculation of 23-09 should be

```
0.98433 - ((0.98433 - 0.96725) * 0.786) = 0.9709051200000001
```

But my code outputs 1.009618. What am I doing wrong here ?

******EDIT******_____

```
data = pd.read_csv('EURUSD=X.csv')
data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Gmt time'])
data = data.set_index('DateTime')
data.drop(['Gmt time'], axis=1, inplace = True)
data.index = data.index.normalize()
data

    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
DateTime                    
2003-04-05  1.12284 1.12338 1.12242 1.12305 29059.0996
2003-04-05  1.12274 1.12302 1.12226 1.12241 26091.8008
2003-04-05  1.12235 1.12235 1.12160 1.12169 29240.9004
2003-05-05  1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
2003-05-05  1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992
... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-09-23  0.97173 0.97239 0.97048 0.97070 31292.5800
2022-09-23  0.97071 0.97185 0.96809 0.96907 32777.4800
2022-09-23  0.96906 0.96939 0.96680 0.96725 35444.2500
2022-09-23  0.96724 0.96947 0.96724 0.96910 19464.9700
2022-09-23  0.96908 0.96967 0.96869 0.96885 7932.2700

data_2 = data[['Close']].copy()
data_2 = data_2.tail(24000)
data_2

def fibonacci(x, v=0.786):
    closemax = x.max()
    closemin = x.min()
    return closemax - ((closemax - closemin) * v)


data_2["fibonacci786up"] = (
    data_2.groupby(["DateTime"])["Close"]
    .expanding(1)
    .apply(lambda x: fibonacci(x, 0.786))
).values

data_2


Close   fibonacci786up
DateTime        
2018-11-19  1.13977 1.133140
2018-11-19  1.13971 1.133369
2018-11-19  1.14028 1.133750
2018-11-19  1.14093 1.133774
2018-11-19  1.14179 1.134075
... ... ...
2022-09-23  0.97070 1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96907 1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96725 1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96910 1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96885 1.009618

print(data_2.tail(24))

             Close  fibonacci786up
DateTime                           
2022-09-22  0.98346        1.007020
2022-09-22  0.98321        1.007405
2022-09-22  0.98383        1.007405
2022-09-23  0.98433        1.007405
2022-09-23  0.98371        1.007405
2022-09-23  0.98278        1.007467
2022-09-23  0.98233        1.008597
2022-09-23  0.98227        1.009254
2022-09-23  0.98293        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.98121        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97751        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97530        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97622        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97500        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97511        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97555        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97339        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97045        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97171        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.97070        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96907        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96725        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96910        1.009618
2022-09-23  0.96885        1.009618
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: issue is elsewhere look for modifications in other parts of the code.

In general the part of the code that you shared works as expected.

```
data = { 
    'DateTime':  ['2022-09-22', '2022-09-22', '2022-09-22', '2022-09-23', '2022-09-23'], 
    'Close': [ 0.98346  , 0.98321, 0.98383, 0.98433, 0.96725],
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)


def fibonacci(x, v=0.786):
    closemax = x.max()
    closemin = x.min()
    return closemax - ((closemax - closemin) * v)


data["fibonacci786up"] = (
    data.groupby(["DateTime"])["Close"]
    .expanding(1)
    .apply(lambda x: fibonacci(x, 0.786))
).values

print("---output---")
print(data)
```

and the output is

```
     DateTime    Close
0  2022-09-22  0.98346
1  2022-09-22  0.98321
2  2022-09-22  0.98383
3  2022-09-23  0.98433
4  2022-09-23  0.96725
---output---
     DateTime    Close  fibonacci786up
0  2022-09-22  0.98346        0.983460
1  2022-09-22  0.98321        0.983264
2  2022-09-22  0.98383        0.983343
3  2022-09-23  0.98433        0.984330
4  2022-09-23  0.96725        0.970905
```

here is an example
https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/cfYI604bjtur

The last row result matches the one that you desire (`0.9709051200000001`), so your code works fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the quick reply!
I'm looking and looking but can't seem to find the problem
I have edited my original question to include my complete code I am using